# Regex for neuracache

Tags: regex

I am trying to integrate an Neuracache style for questions and answers to do spaced repetition in my Obsidian notes (note taking app). So far I have this regex:

`((?:[^\n][\n]?)+) #flashcard ?\n*((?:\n(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*))+)`

But it does not do quite what I want.

I would like to have a regex that will match the following:

```
How do we achieve A? #flashcard                    
To achieve A we need to do the following:          
                                                   
Do B                                               
                                                   
Do C                                               
                                                   
Finally do D                                       
                                                   
---


How do we achieve W? #flashcard                    
To achieve W we need to do the following:          
                                                   
Do Y                                               
                                                   
Do Z                                               
                                                   
<!--
```

We need to capture the question before flashcard and we need to capture the answer that will be in a new line right after #flashcard and right before --- or <!--.

The regex that I have does not accept multiple paragraphs as answers, nor does it take into account the ---

Any idea what I can do to improve my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^(.*?)\s*#flashcard\n([^:]+):.*?^(\S[^\n]+)\s+(?:---|<!--)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/0hvVrx/2)

This will extract the sentence before `#flashcard`, next line and the last answer before `---` or `<!--`

Comment: the |Question and |Answer won't be part of the string, they are there just to show what should be captured as Question and as answer. I edited the post to make that more clear

Comment: Still not quite what I need..I see 2 problems:
One is in the Question session...The question has to be a one liner in the same line as #flashcard, so words above it should not get matched.
And the second problem would be that --- and <!-- should not be included in the match, just used to know where is the end of the match.

Comment: I think I found some alternative...
```(^[^\n]+)\s+#flashcard\s+([\s\S]*?(?=---|<!--|$(?![\r\n])))```